# If $f$ is continuous and strictly positive on $[a,b]$, show that $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f $ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

If $f$ is continuous and strictly positive on $[a,b]$, show that $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f $ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$.

So i know that since $f$ is continuous, $\exists c \in [a,b]$ with $F'(c)=f(c)$. (by a theorem). I am stuck here though.

Answer (score 5):

Two ways:

1. You have $F'(x)=f(x)>0$, so $f$ is strictly increasing.
2. You have, for $y>x$, $F(y)-F(x)=\int_x^y f>0$ (note that since $f>0$ and it is continuous, on any closed interval $[x,y]$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(t)\geq\delta$ for all $t\in[x,y]$.

Answer (score 0):

$F(x+h)-F(x)
=\int_x^{x+h} f(t) dt
$.

If $f$ is strictly positive,
for any finite interval
$[a, b]$
there exists
$ c(a, b) > 0
$
such that
$x \in [a, b] 
\implies f(x) \ge c[a, b]
$.

Therefore
$F(x+h)-F(x)
=\int_x^{x+h} f(t) dt
\ge\int_x^{x+h} c(x, x+h) dt
=ch
\gt 0
$.